# Find Hours Between Startdate and Enddate of different table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
TimeSheetData timesheetdata = new TimeSheetData();
TimeSheet timeSheet = new TimeSheet();
TimeSheetData timesheetdata = new TimeSheetData();
                        timeSheet.StartDate = thisWeekStart;
                        timeSheet.EndDate = thisWeekEnd;
                        timesheetdata.Date = dt;

                        string HourData = item.Value;
                        string TaskID = item.ID.Split(':')[0];
                        timesheetdata.TaskID = Guid.Parse(TaskID);
                        timesheetdata.TimeSheet = timeSheet;
                        timesheetdata.Hours = Convert.ToDouble(HourData);
                        db.TimesheetData.Add(timesheetdata);
                        db.SaveChanges();                  



var TMS = db.TimeSheets.Where(t => t.StartDate == thisWeekStart 
                                   && t.EndDate == thisWeekEnd).ToList();
```

My tables are:

- `Timesheets` (Guid, Startdate, Enddate)
- `TimeSheetDatas` (Guid, hours, Date, Task  GUID, Timesheet Guid)

I want to find hours (`TimesheetDatas`) between `StartDate` and `EndDate` (`Timesheets`).

```
 Hours find = var TMS
```

Comment: Even after editing your question is still highly unclear. `timesheetdata.Hours` can be any number between `-1,79769313486232E+308` and `1,79769313486232E+308`. How are you going to compare that to date values? The LINQ query is just a dummy, it doesn't look like a serious attempt. Please give sample data and explain where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide some details but do you want something like that;

```
var query = from ts in db.TimeSheets
join tsd in db.TimesheetDatas on ts.Guid equals tsd.TimesheetGuid
where ts.StartDate > thisWeekStart && ts.StartDate < thisWeekEnd
select tsd.hour
```

Comment: var query = from ts in db.TimeSheets
                                join tsd in db.TimesheetData on ts.ID equals tsd.TimeSheet.ID
                                where ts.StartDate > thisWeekStart && ts.StartDate < thisWeekEnd
                                select tsd.Hours;.. this is not work

Comment: Yes i want linq  to find hours(TimeSheetsdatas) between Startdate and EndDate(Timesheets)

Comment: thisweekstart=StartDate and thisweekEnd=EndDate

Comment: " this is not work" would you explain it in more detail ?

Comment: I want  Hours which is in TIMESHEETDATAS table . But the condition is the hours come is present between StartDate and EndDate of TIMESHEETS table. The StartDate and Enddate save by the thisweekstart and thisweekend in db.  The hours came i show in textboxe sby the help of view bag.

Comment: So, "thisweekstart=StartDate and thisweekEnd=EndDate" put the where clause this condition. Would you share sample data in your tables.

Comment: My TimeSheetdatas Table(id,Hours,date,TaskId,TimesheetID),,,,MyTimeSheets Table(id,StartDate,EndDate) The answer you give to me is something right but hours are not come

Comment: I want to see your records how is looking like.

Comment: Just share a few records as grid in your answer.

Comment: Timesheetsdata ID...4094C271-EAD4-E711-9666-000C297C9306
 Hours....15
date.....2017-11-27 00:00:00.000
TaskID.....F2886EC7-47D3-E711-9666-000C297C9306
TimeSheetID.....3F94C271-EAD4-E711-9666-000C297C9306